# Inconsistent behavior when uploading files to S3 - 403 forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am running a build process on a CI server (Codeship). This build is creating two files, a JavaScript file and a HTML file. After the build succeeded, these files will be uploaded to Amazon AWS S3. While the JS upload works as expected, the HTML will **always** return a 403 Forbidden when I try to request the file. Both files are uploaded using the very same commands:

```
...
"upload-script": "aws s3 cp ./dist/this.js $BUCKET --region eu-central-1 --acl public-read",
"upload-user-id": "aws s3 cp ./dist/that.html $BUCKET --region eu-central-1 --acl public-read",
...
```

I already tried flushing the bucket manually and setting permissions in the AWS Management Console, yet, no matter what I do: `this.js` is publicly accessible, `that.html` will give me a 403.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your bucket policy? (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html). Maybe *.js files have other permissions than *.html files?

Comment: I never set up anything like this yet, could this be set up all by itself?

Comment: Yes, via the console or aws cli.